# redirect request uri to mirror site using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, maintenance-mode

I have a website. I created a mirror of it and uploaded it in a directory called 'mirror'.  What I wanted to do is whenever a viewer access for example..

```
http://www.example.com/this-page/another-segment/?id=1
```

I want him to be redirected to..

```
http://www.example.com/mirror/this-page/another-segment/?id=1
                       ^^^^^^
```

(I am doing this because I want to want to edit my site's design but I don't want viewers to see the changes in progress until they are complete.  Thus I want to redirect them to the mirrored snapshot, at least temporarily.)

Please suggest how this can be done using .htaccess or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after browsing around the internet. i came up with the idea of putting a **/$1**, a **rewritebase** and **followsymlinks** on the answer givien by appclay

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mirror/
RewriteRule (.*) /mirror/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mirror/
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /mirror/$1 [R]
```

In your .htaccess file.

Comment: i tried localhost/index.html .and i put index.html inside the mirror folder but it didn't work

Comment: Yeah that was a bit of a silly mistake, I put the () group in the regex then failed to use it in the rewrite! I'll edit it so no one copies my mistake...